# No operation command

Tags: powershell, no-op

With Bash, you have the command `:`

```
Null command.

No effect; the command does nothing.

Exit Status:
Always succeeds.
```

Example

```sh
: 'foo'
```

Does PowerShell have something similar to this?

Comment: @DejanDakić `;` would not work with my example. It would generate `foo` instead of nothing.

Comment: Use `Out-Null` to delete the output, if that's what you're seeking, as in `'foo' | Out-Null`

Comment: @StevenPenny: My assumption was that if 'foo' isn't executed, then it's not required, but then I guess I fundamentally misunderstood the docs I found on the colon operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the above example, the `ForEach-Object` alias `%` works

```sh
% 'foo'
```

Or

```sh
function : {}
: 'foo'
```

Or

```sh
[void] 'foo'
```

[PowerShell Data Types](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-datatypes.html)

Comment: Could you please explain what the code in your second example actually means?  Isn't the colon supposed to be for variable namespaces in PowerShell?  Why aren't both lines syntax errors?  Thanks!

Comment: @ScottGartner `:` only has that meaning when used as part of the variable syntax. If a character can be printed using Write-Host without quoting it, it's valid for defining the function name as part of the function statement – though there may be an edge-case I'm missing. _((Technically you can use any character as part of a function name, but defining and invoking it becomes a lot trickier, as you wouldn't be able to use the normal syntax.))_

Answer (score 0):

Another even shorter solution is to use the alias of `Where-Object` which is `?`.

This command line does nothing (and succeeds):

```
? .
```

The trick is simply to pass a single-character argument so that the command does not fail and which has no special meaning in powershell.